# Preposition with ,,organisation"

Tags: prepositions

What is correct? Looking forward to working at your organisation or in your organisation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on the context, and if you're addressing an individual or a board. "Organization" often refers to a governing body/business, where "in" would likely be more appropriate than "at", which would refer to a location/headquarters/plant

Some other suggestions,

> I look forward to working with your organization
>
> I look forward to working under your organization
>
> I look forward to working as a member/part of your organization
>
> I look forward to working with you and your organization

Answer (score 0):

In terms of an objective answer, Google Scholar shows:

- [294 hits](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22working+in+your+organization%22&btnG=) for *working in your organization*
- [99 hits](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22working%20in%20your%20organisation%22&btnG=) for *working in your organisation*
- [57 hits](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22working%20at%20your%20organization%22&btnG=) for *working at your organization*
- [20 hits](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22working%20at%20your%20organisation%22&btnG=) for *working at your organisation*

Although this is not definitive, it suggests that, strictly between your two sentences, *in* is the more common preposition to use.

Answer (score 0):

At denotes location, so it is incorrect to use at while stating that you want to work in the organisation as an employee. If your motive is to inform that you are  going to work at the location of the organisation then you should use at instead of in. So, it would be better to use in if you are referring to the organisation not location.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Can you cite references that indicate this reflects general use? Personally, I've heard "...working at [company]" more often than "...working in [company]" - even if that company has multiple locations.